# Update Word2vec Vectors

Tags: python, nlp, similarity, word2vec, sentence-similarity

I have a corpus that contains several documents, for example 10 documents. The idea is to compute the similarity between them and combine the most similar ones into one document. So the result may be 4 documents. What I have done so far is that I iterate over the documents and calculate the most two similar documents and combine them into one document and so on until a threshold. I used Word2vec vectors by taking the mean vector for the whole document. The problem is that as i proceed with the iteration, the longer the document the more similar even if its not that similar due to the presence of more words. Any idea on how to approach this problem?

I used google Word2vec model. The reason: The corpus is not big to train a model.

Note : I do not want to use topic modeling for some specifications. Also the documents are really short, more than half of them may be one sentence.

I really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Did you consider normalizing similarity measure by the size of the documents?

Comment: Thanks, What do you mean by that? How do i do it?  I did convert the document to a vector representation by summing up all words vectors of the corresponding document and dividing by the number of words in that document. Is there any further action i should do?

Comment: You can try the weighted average as discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47727078/712995

Comment: Thanks Maxim. I did the weighted average but still have the problem, the longer the document the more similar.